# How to test anonymous function in setTimeout using Jasmine

Tags: jasmine

I have this code ES6 Javascript

```js
runAnimation() {
    this.animationTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.strokePath.style.strokeDashoffset = this.currentOffsetValue;
        this.progressCount.innerHTML = this.currentValue;
        this.runAnimation();
    }, this.opts.duration);
}
```

and how to test setTimeout anonymous function?

```js
this.animationTimer = setTimeout(() => {
    this.strokePath.style.strokeDashoffset = this.currentOffsetValue;
    this.progressCount.innerHTML = this.currentValue;
    this.runAnimation();
}, this.opts.duration);
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it myself.
My solution is make other function at setTimeout.

before

```js
setTimeout( () => {
  this.strokePath.style.strokeDashoffset = this.currentOffsetValue;
  this.progressCount.innerHTML = this.currentValue;
  this.runAnimation();  
}, 100);
```

after

```js
setTimeout(this.timerAnimationTimeout.bind(this), 100);


timerAnimationTimeout() {
  this.strokePath.style.strokeDashoffset = this.currentOffsetValue;
  this.progressCount.innerHTML = this.currentValue;
  this.runAnimation();
}
```